# How to keep BSD sockets connected in ios 5.0+ after iphone gets locked

Tags: iphone, sockets, ios5

My webserver's sockets get disconnected on iphone lock. I am using system calls to handle socket functionality in my app. Is there a way in which I can enable voip flags using system calls so that stay active after iphone gets locked or can I implement a voip socket flag setting functionality as it is done in Objective C.

This problem I understand is seen in ios 5.0+ versions. There is not much help around for this in web. Please let me know if some one has successfully got around this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Locking iPhone disconnects sockets on iOS 5 only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270860/locking-iphone-disconnects-sockets-on-ios-5-only)