# tcp socket issue in iOS 5 when iPhone goes to sleep mode

Tags: ios, ios5, tcp, background

I am building a voip application in which the iPhone listens to incoming SIP messages on TCP port 5060.

when the application is in foreground it processes incoming SIP packets on TCP properly.Similarly when I Press Home button,the application goes in background and then also incoming SIP packets are handled properly.

But when after 60 seconds when iPhone goes to sleep mode the 5060 TCP port gets closed and incoming SIP messages are rejected with "Connection Refused".

Somehow I am not able to fix this issue.Can someone suggest how to fix this issue.

Comment: You can't, iOS 5 has decided to kill network connections on sleep... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866651/iphone-app-network-connection-disconnect-after-screen-locking-with-new-ios-sdk-5 The best thing would be to prevent the phone from going to sleep automatically.